# Mysql if else with multiple conditions

Tags: mysql, if-statement, conditional-statements

Can anyone of you help me out to build a Select query for the following table like Data.
I have a similar table, from what i need to select query is with the following conditions
Get all records where
1. delete is '0'
2. AND If delete is '1' then the year should be > 2019
3. AND If delete is '1' and Year is = 2019 then the month should be > 2

```
------------------------------------
id , name , delete , year , month
------------------------------------
1 , apple ,     0 , 0000 , 0 
2 , orange ,    1 , 2019 , 3 
3 , grapes ,    1 , 2018 , 4 
4 , Banana ,    1 , 2019 , 1 
5 , Pears ,     0 , 0000 , 0 
6 , Pineapple , 1 , 2020 , 3 
7 , watermelon ,1 , 2019 , 2
```

The Results should be

```
1 , apple ,     0 , 0000 , 0 
2 , orange ,    1 , 2019 , 3 
5 , Pears ,     0 , 0000 , 0 
6 , Pineapple , 1 , 2020 , 3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  Table1
  Where
     `delete` = 0
     OR (`delete` = 1 AND `year` > 2019)
     OR (`delete` = 1 AND `year` = 2019 AND `month` > 2)
```

The result http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c7ae8f/1